# Debug ruby code line by line in Aptana Studio3 in Ruby on Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using Rails 3.0.12 and ruby 1.9 , Aptana Studio 3. I just started to learn ruby on rails and i got one sample project from open source, i want to debug and see the flow of compiling. I am not getting how to debug rails application line by line and how i see the values while debugging?

Answer (score 0):

First go to the project directory and install bundle using following command. 
 `bundle install` 
 Then create database using following command. 
 `rake db:create` 
 Then migrate database.
`rake db:migrate` 
 Finally start rails server using following command.
 `rails s` if your rails version is `>3.x` or for rails version `2.x` use `ruby script/server` and finally run your roject at browser with `localhost:3000` .

Comment: The important link for ror beginner http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644978/what-is-ruby-on-rails-how-do-i-use-it/11645308#11645308

Answer (score 0):

There are several options on how to debug.

Both require installing of **ruby-debug-ide** gem to your gemset.

### First approach (no tests, no migration)

Open 'App explorer' view, select your project in combo box there, and find little gears icon. There is a 'Debug server' option if you click on that little gears icon. This will allow you to test only your app's code (no tests and no migrations)

### Second approach (debug anything)

Set up debug configuration for debugging ruby project as follows:

1. Open '*Debug configurations*' dialog (by searching 'Debug configurations' in Quick Access text field)
2. Create debug configuration under '*Ruby Application*'
3. On *Main* tab enter path to script that you are going to run depending on what you want to do

   3.1. If you want to just **run your app**, enter path to *rails* script, but I've never tried it

   3.2. If you want to **run migration**, enter path to *rake* script, for example

   ```
   /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3221/bin/rake
   ```

   3.3. If you want to **run your tests**, enter path to *rake_test_loader* script, for example

   ```
   /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3221/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb
   ```
4. On *Arguments* tab set up '*Working directory*' to your app home, and enter params for run depending on what you want to do

   4.1. If you want to just **run your app**, set *Program Arguments* to `start` (I guess)

   4.2. If you want to **run migration**, set *Program Arguments* to required rake task, for example `redmine:plugins:migrate`

   4.3. If you want to **run your tests**, set corresponding params. In my case, in order to debug integration tests, I used next configuration:

   *Interpreter arguments*:

   ```
   -I"lib:test" -I"/home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails2661/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib"
   ```

   *Program arguments*:

   ```
   "test/integration/**/*_test.rb"
   ```